# How to attach different paths in FROM Uri - Spring XML

Tags: apache-camel

Im having trouble trying to attach different paths to a FROM Uri in the Xml configuration file, in java it can be done like this:

```
String[] uris = new String[]{"file:source/path1","file:source/path2"};
from (uris).to("file:dest/path")
```

The resulting route will move the files from the source paths to the destination path, how can i achieve this using Spring XML? i have been trying different aproachs and can't find to have any of them working

```
<route id="bar">
    <from uri= "file:source/path1,file:source/path2" />
    <to uri="file:dest/path"/>
</route>
```

Fabian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple `from` :

```
<route id="bar">
    <from uri="file:source/path1"/>
    <from uri="file:source/path2"/>
    <to uri="file:dest/path"/>
</route>
```

This create one RouteDefinition, but 2 Route instances

Comment: It works! thanks, what if the uris need to be set dynamically? ,i have to make a db query to get the paths and then input them to the route

Comment: you can have external parameters in a route-definition, but this parameters come from properties - if you wants to query a db to create your route, you should use a java RouteBuilder, not a xml configuration